# Как задать комбинацию клавиш или короткую команду для вызова другой команды?

Tags: vim, vimrc

К примеру, вбивать постоянно TlistToggle, NERDTree утомительно, а открывать их с запуском vim тоже не хочется.

Как задать комбинацию клавиш или синоним (вроде :tlist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

любую команду можно «сократить»/упростить с помощью команды `command`.

например, если команду `TlistToggle` (которая, конечно, достаточно проста и сама по себе: её совсем несложно «вбить», воспользовавшись авто-дополнением) требуется вызывать командой `:Tlist` (пользовательские команды должны начинаться с заглавной буквы), то прямо в *vim* так и введите:

```
:command Tlist TlistToggle
```

слово `command` в данном случае можно сократить до `com`.

чтобы данное описание всегда загружалось при старте программы *vim*, можно добавить его (естественно, без предваряющего символа двоеточия `:`), например, в основной конфигурационный файл (в *unix-like* системах это `~/.vimrc`).

---

подробнее смотрите в справке: `:help command` или [онлайн1](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command) [онлайн2](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#:com).

---

**чтобы «обойти» требование первой заглавной буквы** вместо `command` можно использовать `cabbrev`:

```
:cabbrev tlist TlistToggle
```

слово `cabbrev` можно сократить до `ca`.

Comment: Автор "Practical Vim" в [What's new in Practical Vim, 2nd edition](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2015/11/whats-new-in-practical-vim-2nd-edition/) пишет, что [vimdoc.sourceforge.net](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command) не обновлялось с 2010 года и ссылается на [vimhelp.appspot.com](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/).

Comment: @hobo-mts, спасибо, добавил ещё одну ссылку.

Answer (score 4):

В `~/.vimrc` добавьте: `map <F7> :NERDTree<CR>` и перезапустите vim.

После чего, по нажатию клавиши `<F7>` будет открываться NERDTree.